# NSBundle pathForResource method

Tags: iphone

```
NSURL *modelURL1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"MyTest" withExtension:@"momd"];
NSLog(@"%@", [modelURL1 absoluteURL]);

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"MyTest" ofType:@"momd"];
NSURL *modelURL = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
NSLog(@"%@", [modelURL absoluteURL]);
```

The first line is generated by XCode when I use Core Data, but it does not work because the method doesn't work prior to iOS 4. So I need another method, I thought I could use the second one but it returns nil...Why does it not work?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second one doesn't work because path isn't a URL. Use this instead:

```
NSURL *modelURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you explain why it works? I do not see the difference.

Comment: `+URLWithString:` expects a string with a URL in it, as in "file:///foo/bar". path doesn't contain a URL, just a path (as in "/foo/bar"), as expected by `+fileURLWithPath:`.